# HTML5 like placeholder

Tags: ckeditor, placeholder

Is there a plugin or built-in functionality for CKEditor 4.x that would act like HTML5 input/textarea placeholder?

Only thing I found is http://ckeditor.com/addon/placeholder, but that seems to be something a lot different.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the [configHelper plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/confighelper).

Demo: http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/placeholder-text-in-ckeditor.html