# How to give default placeholder text to the textarea in ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor, text-editor

Searhced a lot  for this. I have been trying to add placeholder text in ckeditor using one of its plugins "configuration Helper" plugin for CkEditor.

How to give default placeholder text to the textarea in ckeditor?

[image: Placeholder text]

Comment: Is there any live example with sample code or something .

Comment: All I could find there is "How to give default text in dialogs"

Comment: Did you try looking here :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301703/how-do-i-add-a-placeholder-attribute-to-an-instance-of-ckeditor

Comment: Thanks! worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Follow the below steps to add placeholder.

1) Add confighelper plugin to your plugin folder.

2) Add this piece of code to your config:

```
config.extraPlugins='onchange,confighelper';
```

3) In your html page add place holder attribute to your textarea, its mandatory and add

```
 CKEDITOR.replace( '#editor', {             
    extraPlugins : 'confighelper',                                                  
 });
```

4) Now you can enjoy.

Comment: before that you have to download config helper from ckeditor website

Answer (score -1):

In HTML5 ther is a placeholder attribute

```
<textarea placeholder="Describe yourself here..."></textarea>
```

Otherwise you need javscript to do it
To check which browsers are compatible have a look at: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_placeholder.asp