# Trying to add placeholder to CKeditor 4, but not having any luck

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm simply trying to configure certain settings for certain ckeditor, and having no luck. For one, I do have a `views/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js` that *works*, but this is a "global" config file.

On certain views in my rails app, I want to have other settings, like placeholders for example. I'm not sure if version 4 includes a lot of changes compared to some of the older ones, but here are some other stackoverflow references that I've used:

[How do I add a placeholder attribute to an instance of CKEditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301703/how-do-i-add-a-placeholder-attribute-to-an-instance-of-ckeditor)

This one in particular suggests using `CKEDITOR.replace("myeditor" , config );` to replace the placeholder, but that doesn't work for me. When I replace "myeditor" with the ID of my `textarea` element, such as this: `CKEDITOR.replace("randomTextAreaID" , {placeholder: "Hello World"} );`, I get this error:

> Uncaught The editor instance "randomTextAreaID" is already
>   attached to the provided element.

There are other suggestions that appear as "hacks" from 2012, but that is 6 years ago. Can't imagine that setting a placeholder for a text editor would be this difficult.

** EDIT **

So I got it to work like this:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['randomTextAreaID'];
if (editor) { editor.destroy(true); }
CKEDITOR.replace( 'randomTextAreaID', {
height: 20, 
});
```

but still looks like trying to set a placeholder isn't working.

I've also downloaded the placeholder plugin and placed it here: `views/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/plugins/placeholder` and still no luck. No javascript loading errors, just simply not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use placeholders, please add this [plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/placeholder) to your CKEditor build. Since the placeholder require plugins which also have couple of dependencies, I would recommend using [online builder](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder). Simply select your package (e.g. standard), add placeholder plugin and the builder will take care of dependencies. Next download the minified version.

Once you have that working you need to add place holder in instance configuration (config.js is a global configuration, while configuration in replace method is instance specific):

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'randomTextAreaID', {
height: 20, 
extraPlugins : 'placeholder'
});
```

Place holders can be inserted using placeholder dialog. They will also auto-change (e.g. your initial content) text like `[[any text]]` to placeholder. To use more technical terms - this text will be upcasted to placeholder [widget](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_widgets.html).

Please also see the placeholder demo in action: https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/placeholder.html

Answer (score 1):

```
 ckeConfig = {
    extraPlugins: 'placeholder'
  };
```

```
 <ckeditor id="editor1"  [config]="ckeConfig"
       (namespaceLoaded)="onNamespaceLoaded($event)"
       [(data)]="editorData">
   </ckeditor>
```

```
public onNamespaceLoaded( event ) {
    event.on('dialogDefinition', function(event) {
      if ('placeholder' == event.data.name) {
        var input = event.data.definition.getContents('info').get('name');
        input.id= 'aps-placeholders',
        input.type = 'select';
        input.items = [ ['Company'], ['Email'], ['First Name'], ['Last Name'] , ['City'] , ['Province'] , ['Province']];
        input.setup = function() {
          this.setValue('Company');
        };
      }
      });
}
```

Add this method in ts. Solution is for angular(2+)