# Adding placeholder to ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, placeholder

I'm using ckeditor and I'm trying to set a placeholder inside it, but it's not working i added this to my js code:

```
    $(function () {
    var config = {};
    config.placeholder = 'some value';
    CKEDITOR.replace("myeditor" , config );

});
```

Can anybody clarify to me how to add placeholder using this plugin? because i didn't find clear steps to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 like placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558310/html5-like-placeholder)

Comment: Do you see a [P] button in the toolbar ? That's how you insert the placeholder

Comment: @A.Iglesias i'm using the same plugin but it's not working for me, do you know how to use it correctly?

Comment: @Imhotep this plugin adds a placeholder to the editor like html5 placeholders

Comment: `CKEDITOR.replace( 'myeditor', {
   extraPlugins: 'placeholder',
   height: 220
  } );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the plugin, it takes the placeholder from the HTML attribute. And you're not configuring the plugin when you call the `.replace` function. So...

**HTML**:

```
<textarea name="myeditor" placeholder="some value"></textarea>
```

**JQUERY**:

```
var config = { extraPlugins: 'confighelper' };
CKEDITOR.replace('myeditor',config);
```

Here you have a working fiddle...

https://fiddle.jshell.net/rigobauer/25snLg8w/

I hope it helps